# Chrome device emulation touch not working

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am working on some changes to a website for a client. I cannot get chrome's device emulation to work properly. I select iphone 6, and the page renders correctly, however I cannot click any links or buttons. It seems the touchscreen device emulation is not functioning as expected.

The website is http://ticketofficeeventsales.com/

Comment: It works fine when you choose **Galaxy S5**.

When choosing the iPhone 6, there is a javascript error caused by an undefined variable. This is likely the cause of your problem.

Comment: Ah, that looks to be the problem. Thanks